# NTFS permission with modify date

Tags: powershell, acl

I want to export NTFS permissions of folders and subfolders on the server to a CSV.
It should show users and groups with permissions and last modify date of folders.

Here is what I have got so far, but it doesn't show modify date and it exports disorganize.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\FILES\ -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsContainer} |
  Get-Acl | % {
    $path = $_.Path
    $_.Access | % {
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Folder      = $path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")
        Access      = $_.FileSystemRights
        Control     = $_.AccessControlType
        User        = $_.IdentityReference
        Inheritance = $_.IsInherited
      }
    }
  } | ? {$_.Inheritance} | Export-Csv C:\Users\test_dump.csv -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where using a convoluted oneliner is hurting you.  An actual script is much more readable.

```
# set path to search
$SearchPath = 'C:\FILES'

# file for results
$ExportFile = 'C:\temp\testdump.csv'

# get list of folders
# if you're using PS v2 use | where{$_.psIsContainer} instead of -Directory to filter for directories
$FolderList = Get-ChildItem $SearchPath -Directory -Recurse

# get list of subfolders
foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    $FolderACL = Get-Acl $Folder.FullName 

    # get list of access objects for each folder
    foreach ($Access in $FolderACL.Access) {

        # Filter to only show explicit permissions
        # if ($Access.IsInherited) { Return }

        # custom object to hold the access object + path + lastwrite
        $export = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Folder  = $FolderACL.Path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","")
            Access  = $Access.FileSystemRights
            Control = $Access.AccessControlType
            User    = $Access.IdentityReference
            Inheritance = $Access.IsInherited
            LastModified = $Folder.LastWriteTime
        }
        $export | Export-CSV -Path $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation -Append

    }

}
```

In your pipeline, you had `| ? {$_.Inheritance}`.  This is only going to show you inherited permissions.  I suspect you want the opposite.  IF this is the case, uncomment the explicit permissions filter.

Answer (score 0):

Move one `ForEach-Object` before the `Get-Acl`, and use the `DirectoryInfo` objects for path and modification time. I'd also filter for inherited permissions before creating the objects (creating objects first and throwing them away later is a waste of resources).

```
$root = 'C:\files'
$csv  = 'C:\path\to\test_dump.csv'

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_
    Get-Acl $dir | Select-Object -Expand Access |
      Where-Object { $_.IsInherited } |
      ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          Folder       = $dir.FullName
          Access       = $_.FileSystemRights
          Control      = $_.AccessControlType
          User         = $_.IdentityReference
          Inheritance  = $_.IsInherited
          LastModified = $dir.LastWriteTime
        }
      }
  } | Export-Csv $csv -Force
```

If you have at least PowerShell v3 you can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` instead of having to filter for `$_.PSIsContainer`.