# How to add folder path to ACL output

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I have a PS script that displays the permissions for each subfolder in a certain location. I'd like to add the path to the output so that you can see who has access to what folder. Below is what I have so far. I know this should be simply ... but its been a long day.

```
CLS
$Path = "\\Server\Folder"
$UDate=Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
$OutputFile = "\\Server\OutputFolder\Permissions_$UDate.csv"
$ClientFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
$Report = ""
$ACL = ""

Foreach ($SubFolder in $ClientFiles)
{
    $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $SubFolder.FullName 
    $acl.Access | ForEach-Object {$_.identityReference.value | Where-Object { $_ -ne 'CREATOR OWNER' -and $_ -ne 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' -and $_ -ne 'BUILTIN\Administrators'}} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cleaned up a one-liner that does the same thing.  So I'm thinking this is a homework question.

In your innermost loop, create a custom object and put all the properties you want to capture on the custom object and export that object to a csv.

[NTFS permission with modify date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33378426/4446881)

Comment: How about sharing your one-liner?

Comment: @user5493949 I didn't create the one liner, I turned a complicated oneliner into a functioning script.  And I linked it in my answer about the same time you asked for it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the script! After looking at it I'm trying how to filter the results by adding " | ? {$_.identityReference -ne 'CREATOR OWNER'} " after the final bracket but that account is still showing in the results. any suggestions?

Comment: @user5493949 I think you want to remove all access control entries except those for "CREATOR OWNER".  Go where the inheritance filter is located and do one for `if($Access.identityReference -ne 'CREATOR OWNER'') {continue}`.  This will only show 'CREATOR OWNER' entries because the continue here causes PS to skip the rest of the block and do the next iteration.

Comment: That was it! Thanks again!